# Please notify me of the 30,000 character limit

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, character-limit

When [mucking around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/25065#25065) in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), I discovered AFTER all my hard work and effort I put into my 'response' that there is a character limit of 30,000 for posts.

Can there please be a notification of such limit? Whilst we are typing the response would be best, but it could be applied the same way the minimum character limit warning is applied.

Comment: Great, that page crashed my browser. Twice.

Comment: Hrm. Lucky that 40,000 character limit is in place then! God knows what my original 160,000 character long post would have done...

Comment: Damn you joshhunt! Crashed another browser here trying to see what you were making castles of in the sandbox.

Comment: @random: use a different browser ;)

Comment: Bloody hell, can never go back to Formatting Sandbox now. What's that? Another browser? But it looks so odd in IE5.

Comment: Not learning quick enough. Everytime, click that link and it's just stewing not so healthy Oxo cubes.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: But the punctuation sequences are wholly inappropriate; not to mention that he didn't capitalize one of the few characters that _should_ have been capitalized. I am offended by at least 68% of the comment.

Comment: @joshhunt you broke the internet! what was that?

Comment: I just can upvote that... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/long-answers-are-truncated-in-so

Answer (score 9):

You're actually complaining that your enormous post in the *formatting sandbox* was truncated?

I'd be more amenable to this request if someone actually wrote a **real** post that long, and had a legitimate complaint that it got truncated.

edit: we really should be warning users when they enter a novella body text that's too long, rather than just truncating silently. I added a saner check for this through the standard question form validation.

Comment: Oh for I have incurred the wrath of many fallen angels, the weird striations from the Formatting Sandbox leaves the CPU crushed under 99% for opera.exe. Well if that's a sign to stop with Opera, forget that!

Comment: That sounds like [status-declined].

Comment: But couldn't you have just *warned* me that I was close to this limit?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: your ending sentence is beautifuly ironic comming here from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/long-answers-are-truncated-in-so :)

Comment: :-) Yeah well, Jeff always writes on his blog that he sucks so you can't really blame him.

Comment: @e-satis: don't we all?

Comment: _Cough Cough_ You can send a POST request straight to the chat servers

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing anything 40,000 characters long (about equal to 7K English words) in one piece for any Internet forum, you're doing it wrong.  Srsly.

Comment: Piffle. 7K words is just starting to get into the meat of a subject. There's never any need to go below 1K...oh...wait...

Comment: Yeah, and 640K of memory should be enough for anybody, after all.

Comment: Computers change a lot faster than humans do.  It's now easy to get programs that take lots of megabytes of memory, and they sometimes load and run almost as fast as their counterparts back when processors ran in single-digit MHz.  I can't read a short story any faster than when 48K was a whole lot of memory.