# Is it acceptable to post full solution to a big programming problem?

Tags: discussion

During the writing of almost standard program, but in new area programmers are faced with standard mini-problems which are not covered in the documentation. Solutions are scattered everywhere on the internet. But it'd be better if full solution would be in one place. Is it acceptable to post such solutions on SO? Is it acceptable to post solutions to near-programming problems? For example, starting with GitHub in Windows is not so simple, despite detailed guide.

Comment: See Jeff Atwood's answer:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/long-answers-are-truncated-in-so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer on Stack Overflow can contain about 30,000 characters.  If you can condense it down to that size or less, I say go for it.

Make sure you [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first!  If your question is properly scoped, you should be able to write a detailed answer to it, and stay well within the 30,000 character answer limit.

I only wish more people would take the time to write detailed answers.  I think we err on the side of brevity.