# Max length check ignores markup, results in truncation of long, formatted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, editor, truncation

First reported [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/whats-the-upper-character-limit-for-a-posts-size-and-implement-a-warning-sys#question) by [haylem](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3631/haylem).

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Construct a post consisting of exactly 30,000 non-markup characters (no HTML or Markdown formatting). Here's one for you: [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/139319#139319)
2. Edit it to add some more non-markup text. For instance, a period at the end.
3. Try to submit the edit. Note the error:

   [image: body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 30001]
4. Reverting your previous edit, make a new one consisting only of markup. Bold a word, or add a link:

   [image: wrapping the last word in double apostrophes to bold it]
5. Submit this edit, and note that while the text submitted is now even longer than in #3, the edit is accepted. But the post is truncated at 30000 characters:

   [image: the last four characters chopped off]

This is really the worst of both worlds: the editor isn't forced to limit his text, but the text itself is cut or mangled to some degree (chopping off the link table found at the end of long, well-referenced posts is particularly cruel).

I suspect this behavior was introduced with the recent change to validate *minimum* length after first stripping markup. That behavior is **good** - it ensures the spirit of the minimum length check is preserved by disallowing markup tricks and excessive linking to subvert it.

#### Recommended solution

For ease of use, the *maximum* length check should be done *prior to* stripping HTML, thus preserving the (relatively) friendly warnings instead of the (extremely) unfriendly truncation.

Alternately, the truncation behavior could be removed entirely, allowing 30000 *displayed* characters and however much markup is desired.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I suspect this behavior was introduced with the recent change to validate *minimum* length after first stripping markup.

That's correct, the *maximum* length check was accidentally changed to be based on the converted and stripped version as well.

Since the maximum length is still enforced on the Markdown source, but the validation happened on the converted/stripped version (which has a good chance of being shorter), the truncation took place.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks (and thanks to @Shog9).