# Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 26618, so what?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

So... um, what?

Here's [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508281/minify-media-query). I removed the unbeautified minified CSS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You did enter more than 30000 characters. The length check uses the correct number (well, [these days it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139335/115866)), but the error message still used the incorrect number. Fixed in the next build, thanks!